# Is it possible to deploy multiple instance of stateless service on one Service Fabric node?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Can I deploy multiple instances of a "stateless" microservice on a single Service Fabric node?

Answer (score 0):

You can. You have to create the app with different app type names and assign different port numbers to bind to.